# How to output colours in terminal mac

Tags: zsh

I have a Shell script that should output a text in a colour with this command

```
 echo -e "\e[34mCleaning up\e[0m"
```

But when I output it, I get

```
-e \e[34mCleaning up\e[0m
```

See image

[image: Colour not displaying]

How can I fix this

Comment: Do you use bash or zsh?

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `\e` with `\033`. same as below

```
bash-3.2$  echo -e "\033[34mCleaning up\033[0m"
Cleaning up
bash-3.2$
```